# MVC4 / Ninject - How to change bindings after Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I am using MVC4 with Ninject (4.0.30319) and NinjectWebCommon.cs.  I have Ninject set up and working with a common set of bindings for MVC and the WebAPI.

```
            private static IKernel CreateKernel()
            {
                var kernel = new StandardKernel();
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

                RegisterServices(kernel);

                // Install our Ninject-based IDependencyResolver into the Web API config
                GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectWebAPIDependencyResolver(kernel);

                // Install our Ninject-based IDependencyResolver into the MVC config
                DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectMVCDependencyResolver(kernel));

                return kernel;
            }


            /// <summary>
            /// Load your modules or register your services here!
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
            private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
            {
                kernel.Bind<DBDataContext>().To<DBDataContext>();
                kernel.Bind<IChecksRepository>().To<ChecksRepository>();
                kernel.Bind<IDepartmentsRepository>().To<DepartmentsRepository>();
                kernel.Bind<IEmployeesRepository>().To<EmployeesRepository>();
                kernel.Bind<IScheduleRepository>().To<ScheduleRepository>();
                kernel.Bind<IVacanciesRepository>().To<VacanciesRepository>();
                kernel.Bind<IVacancyTypes>().To<VacancyTypesRepository>();
            }


            public static void RegisterAuthenticatedServices()
            {
                bootstrapper.Kernel.Bind<DBDataContext>().To<DBDataContext>().WithPropertyValue("ChangedByPKID", Globals.UserPKID);
            }
```

In Global.asax I have some one-shot code to determine when the user is authenticated and it calls RegisterAuthenticatedServices to change the binding and it executes without an exception.  The problem is that after the binding is changed and a controller is requested MVC complains that "No parameterless constructor defined for this object" which I am guessing means the DBDataContext binding is trashed in Ninject.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Unbind the context and then bind it back with the changes:

```
        public static void RegisterAuthenticatedServices()
    {
        bootstrapper.Kernel.Unbind<DBDataContext>();
        bootstrapper.Kernel.Bind<DBDataContext>().To<DBDataContext>().WithPropertyValue("ChangedByPKID", Globals.UserPKID);
    }
```